# HTML in OneNote Add-in API

Tags: html, css, node.js, office-js, office-addins

I've created my own OneNote Add-in using Nodejs.  I am having two issues.  I've searched high and low and haven't found a solution.

My add-in adds a new outline to a OneNote page.  This outline contains an HTML table with one column and multiple rows.  I want set the background of some of the HTML table rows.  I have tried everything I could think of, including:

- Setting the bgcolor attribute of TR: `<tr bgcolor='red'>`
- Setting the bgcolor attribute of TD: `<td bgcolor='red'>`
- Setting the style attribute of TR: `<tr style='background-color:red'>`
- Setting the style attribute of TD: `<td style='background-color:red'>`
- Using a separate CSS file
- Using the Hex value for the color (red) #FF0000
- Exporting a OneNote 2016 page as "Single File Web Page (*.mht)", inspecting the contents and trying to replicate that myself.
- Tried to view source on the OneNote web version of my page to inspect a table row that has the background color set. (The page content is buried in so many layers, I can't find the content page source).
- I tried to figure out how to programmatically add HTML content to the page, but [Microsoft's OneNote API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/onenote/onenote.table?view=onenote-js-1.1) doesn't specify how to insert a table.

Noting works.  Additionally, I want one of the cells in my table to use &nbsp and not strip out extra white space.  &nbsp doesn't work.  Neither `<pre>` tag.  OneNote just ignores my markup, except I was able to specify the thickness of the table border `<table border=1>`.

For reference, I cannabalized this sample code: [Build your first OneNote task pane add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/onenote-quickstart)

I used the above sample code to create this:
[taskpane.js in my Github repo](https://github.com/steve3p0/LING511/blob/master/PsuSyntax_OneNoteAddIn/PSU%20Syntax%20OneNote%20Add-in/src/taskpane/taskpane.js)

Comment: To who ever down voted me: please kindly tell me why?  Was my question not clear?  Did I not show what I attempted?  And did I not provide an update that this functionality is not supported?.  And lastly... is this information not helpful to anyone?

Comment: I moved the update to an answer I provided below.  If this question needs to improved or if it isn't appropriate, would someone please educate me?

Comment: After a break of about 2 weeks.  I noticed some of the markup is starting to work.  I didn't do anything.  Even my older OneNote pages that I haven't touched are rendering multiple spaces and I can set the font style.  Odd.  Still no background color yet.  I'll update the solution when more details come forth.

Answer (score 1):

*To answer my own question...*

I found this after posting the question: 
[OneNote API HTML tag support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/dn575442(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

It doesn't appear that Microsoft supports bgcolor, background CSS on tables/tr/td, nor CSS in general with respect to the OneNote API.  The `<pre>` tag and &nbsp is not even listed.

Comment: @Rob, thanks Rob for the feedback.  I was trying just about everything.  The official standard for setting background color using CSS does not work in OneNote.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning,

I know that this is an old post relatively but I couldn't see many others asking the same question and I've just found a solution.

Essentially you can do normal inline styling **but** you need to use the backslash for the quotes inside the "var html =..." line.

For example.

```
var html = "<p style=\"color: blue;font-family:Courier;text-align:center;background-color:yellow;\"> This paragraph shows blue, Courier text</p><table><tr><td style=\"background-color: #D6EEEE;\">A light blue coloured table cell</td></tr></table>"
```

Hopefully I can now find a way to change the whole page colour programatically...

Chris